# Why does Stack Overflow keep rolling back the answer acceptance on my question?

Tags: bug, accepted-answer

Recently I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964537/where-can-i-download-the-spring-dm-jar-files) on Stack Overflow.

After a while there was only one answer, which clarified some points about my question. It wasn't the full answer to my question; however, after one day, I decided to accept it.

But suddenly another answer showed up which was more exact and accurate about the whole question. So I've changed my mind about accepting the first answer and decided to accept the new one. The first answer was unaccepted successfully, but the new one cannot be accepted!

The problem is that, every time I try to accept the newer answer, the system rolls this operation back after a few seconds.

Is there any rule about this behavior or this is a bug?

Comment: The newer one looks accepted to me, and says you accepted it 40 minutes ago...

Comment: Are you referring to the activity a few days ago? [question timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31964537/timeline)

Comment: @TZHX you are absolutely right and it is now accepted. But it is really strange, because this happened to me yesterday I think. It was accepted once, but today I was visiting the forum I've noticed it has been unchecked again and my reputation decreased by 2. I don't know, maybe it's because of a technical issue in submitting AJAX requests.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a bug, or possibly a connection issue. At any rate, it's not intended behaviour.